# Anaconda Navigator and Spyder don't start

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am having a problem opening Spyder or Anaconda Navigator. Anaconda shell still works without a problem.

I already tried:

1. reinstalling Spyder
2. reinstalling Anaconda
3. opening it from shell with the following result:

```sh
(base) C:\Users\***>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

PyQt5 should be installed (I tryed reinstalling and updating)

I also tried to update conda anaconda and python.

Do you have any suggestions? I already googled a lot, but wasn't able to find anything that works for me.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Creating a new env with python 3.8.2 allows me to open spyder, but the window stays a white Window and does not respond any more.
The following ERROR appears in the shell:

```
(newEnv) C:\Users\***>spyder
[2280:2332:0331/162242.873:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: Die Pipe wurde beendet. (0x6D)
[4620:17776:0331/162242.873:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: Die Pipe wurde beendet. (0x6D)
```

Translation: "Die Pipe wurde beendet." - "The pipe was stoped."

Downgrading Python to python 3.7.0 (The last version I know of that it worked) results in the same ERROR from the beginning.

Comment: try creating environment and activate it

Comment: You need to do all of it inside your venv. After recreate your venv, install pyqt and after uninstall and install Spyder.

Comment: First of thanks for your answers. This partialy works for me: "You need to do all of it inside your venv. After recreate your venv, install pyqt and after uninstall and install Spyder" Spyder starts but it is not responding. It stays a white window.

Comment: This is the error message I receive in the shell: (newEnv) C:\Users\***>spyder
[1056:17492:0331/160329.388:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: Die Pipe wurde beendet. (0x6D)
[17280:5224:0331/160329.388:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: Die Pipe wurde beendet. (0x6D)

Comment: "PyQt5 should be installed (I tryed reinstalling and updating)": if you used pip to install pyqt5, then you broke your Anaconda installation and now you have to restart it. The error you show above is probably due to that too.

Comment: I used conda. But assuming I did use pip somewhen by mistake, what do you mean by restart?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error after installing anaconda. What did for me was:

- uninstall all previous Anaconda installations
- extend admin rights to my local account
- select the add PATH option during installation, even if not recommended